# Jackson DateTime formatting for JodaTime with timezone offset using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jodatime, objectmapper

I am upgrading the version of Jackson library and I am stuck with a problem of formatting/parsing Joda DateTime with timezone offset. I have shared the sample code used with two different version of the Jackson library. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong or missing.

**jackson-datatype-joda: 2.2.4**

```
//jackson-datatype-joda: 2.2.4
@Test
public void jodaDateTimeZoneTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getObjectMapper();
    DateTime dateTimeInChicago = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
    DateTime dateTimeInBucharest = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Bucharest"));
    
    System.out.println("the Input Value for Chicago is "+dateTimeInChicago); //Sample input is 2021-01-14T05:32:11.194-06:00
    System.out.println("the Input Value for Bucharest is "+dateTimeInBucharest); //Sample input is 2021-01-14T13:32:11.232+02:00
    Foo fooChicago = new Foo();
    fooChicago.setDateTime(dateTimeInChicago);
    System.out.println("the output value for Chicago is "+mapper.writeValueAsString(fooChicago)); //sample ouput is {"dateTime":"2021-01-14T05:32:11.194-06:00"}

    Foo fooBucharest = new Foo();
    fooBucharest.setDateTime(dateTimeInBucharest);

    System.out.println("the Input Value for Bucharest is "+mapper.writeValueAsString(fooBucharest)); //Sample output is {"dateTime":"2021-01-14T13:32:11.232+02:00"} 
}
```

**jackson-datatype-joda: 2.11.1**

```
//jackson-datatype-joda: 2.11.1
@Test
public void jodaDateTimeZoneTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = getObjectMapper();
    DateTime dateTimeInChicago = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
    DateTime dateTimeInBucharest = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Bucharest"));
    
    System.out.println("the Input Value for Chicago is "+dateTimeInChicago); //Sample input is 2021-01-14T05:34:27.966-06:00
    System.out.println("the Input Value for Bucharest is "+dateTimeInBucharest); //Sample input is 2021-01-14T13:34:28.012+02:00
    Foo fooChicago = new Foo();
    fooChicago.setDateTime(dateTimeInChicago);
    System.out.println("the output value for Chicago is "+mapper.writeValueAsString(fooChicago)); //sample ouput is {"dateTime":"2021-01-14T11:34:27.966Z"}

    Foo fooBucharest = new Foo();
    fooBucharest.setDateTime(dateTimeInBucharest);

    System.out.println("the Input Value for Bucharest is "+mapper.writeValueAsString(fooBucharest)); //Sample output is {"dateTime":"2021-01-14T11:34:28.012Z"} 
}
```

**Common code for both:**

```
private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    return mapper;
}

public class Foo {
    private DateTime dateTime;

    public DateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
}
```

1. With 2.2.4 the value after converting the object to string using
   jackson is 2021-01-14T05:32:11.194-06:00
2. With 2.11.1, the value after converting the object to string using
   jackson is 2021-01-14T11:34:27.966Z
3. In later version, the offset is getting added/subtracted to the
   actual time.

**Expectation:**
How to get the same value with offset(like -06:00) when using higher version of Jackson library?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of JodaTime `DateTimeSerializer` has changed considerably between [2.2](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/2.2/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/ser/DateTimeSerializer.java) and [2.11](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/2.11/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/ser/DateTimeSerializer.java), the last significant change happening in [2.6](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/blob/2.6/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/ser/DateTimeSerializer.java).

Version 2.6 introduced a [`SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID) flag to indicate whether the `DateTime` being serialized should be printed in its own timezone and with the timezone ID (when the feature is enabled) or printed as a corresponding UTC timestamp (when the feature is disabled, default behaviour). However, the effect is that both the timezone offset and timezone ID are printed. If you change your 2.11 code to

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID);
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

you'll find the output to be

```json
{"dateTime":"2021-02-03T08:58:30.632-06:00[America/Chicago]"}
```

The default `DateTimeSerializer` is registered in `JodaModule` when you register the module with the mapper. I have not found a way to override the timezone format (so that only the offset would be printed) when I tried to register a custom instance of `DateTimeSerializer` instead of the default one.

You can however implement and register your own serializer that will format the `DateTime` exactly how you want. Simple example based on the logic of `DateTimeSerializer`:

```
public class CustomDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(FormatConfig.DEFAULT_DATETIME_PRINTER.createFormatter(provider).withOffsetParsed().print(value));
    }
}
```

Then configure your ObjectMapper:

```
private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Instead of .setDateFormat() - see note below
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    // Use all the defaults of JodaModule
    mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    // Override with your custom logic
    SimpleModule customJodaModule = new SimpleModule();
    customJodaModule.addSerializer(DateTime.class, new CustomDateTimeSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(customJodaModule);

    return mapper;
}
```

**Note**: the configuration

```
mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
```

doesn't really affect the format of JodaTime date serialization, but as a side effect it disables the [`SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) feature. You can remove the `mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat)` and instead use

```
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

**Note 2**:
UTC-06:00 and [America/Chicago] are not synonyms - Chicago (and many other places in the world) observes daylight saving time in summer, when it moves to UTC-05:00. You must consider which format suits your purpose best. For optimal interoperability between systems, sending timestamps in the UTC timezone is preferred (how Jackson Joda module behaves by default).

**Note 3**:
You may need to configure a custom deserializer for `DateTime` and custom de-/serializer pairs for other Joda data types whenever the same behaviour of printing only a timezone offset is expected.

Comment: I think this is correct answer. mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule()); mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);, and had to sepecify @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") on the DateTime property inside my Pojo